# Why is my fileprovider location in the files app grey (inactive)

Tags: ios, fileprovider

I have a working fileprovider extension but if I go to the photo album, for example, and share a photo and choose 'Save to Files' my files provider location appears in the list but is grey and inactive so it cannot be chosen.

What do I need to do so that it is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anybody else with this problem:

My problem was that my root container  was "read only" and when looking for places to copy a file too the files app will ignore directories that are "read only" even if they may contain sub directories that are writable.

The FileProviderItem for the root container should also return the typeIdentifier "public.folder"